# There are 10 men, 10 women, and 10 rooms. Each person randomly goes into a room.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

What is the expected number of rooms with at least one man and woman?

Our prof. gave us the following solution however, I'm confused about the probability portion of the answer (especially the $(\frac{9}{10})^{10}$ part):

$$10 \times \left(\!1 - \left(\! \frac{9}{10} \!\right)^{\!\!10}\hspace{1mu}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The chance that a particular room does not have a specific man is $\frac 9{10}$.  The chance that it does not have any men is $\left (\frac 9{10}\right )^{10}$  The chance that it has at least one man is $1-\left (\frac 9{10}\right )^{10}$  The chance that it has at least one man and at least one woman is $\left(1-\left (\frac 9{10}\right )^{10}\right )^2$  For the expected number of rooms with at least one man and at least one woman, multiply by $10$, getting $$10\left(1-\left (\frac 9{10}\right )^{10}\right )^2$$

Comment: We multiply by 10 because that's the no. or rooms, correct?

Comment: @Joel:  Yes.  We are using the linearity of expectation.  The expected number of rooms that succeed is the number of rooms times the chance that any given one succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

The result is true.

It's like the following situation:

You have ten black balls, ten white balls. And there are ten boxes. It's like we randomly throw that balls into the boxes. So for each box $i$, the number of black and white balls that will fall in the box is an event $X_i$. where 
$P(X_i\geq(1,1))=(1-0.9^{10})^2$.

Then we define another variable $Y_i = \begin{cases} 1 & X_i\geq(1,1)\\ 0 &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$, which means that the result of $box_i$ meet the requirements or not. Then we count the number of success. Note this is not binomial experiments, since $Y_i, Y_j, i\neq j$ are not independent. But this does not matter. We just want to know the expectation of $\mathbb{E}(\sum_i Y_i)$, which is exactly the answer.

Comment: That is wrong. I mean, the (Y_i) are not independent, but that's not a problem here. We only want to compute the expectation, which is linear: $\mathbb{E}(\sum_i Y_i) = \sum_i \mathbb{E} (Y_i)$. I agree that getting the full distribution of the $(Y_i)$, or even computing the variance of the sum would be hard, but that's not what is asked.

Comment: @D.Thomine Thanks. But cannot understand $\mathbb{E}(\sum_i Y_i)= \sum_i \mathbb{E}(Y_i)$ ?

Comment: The expectation is linear (it is just an integral).

Comment: @D.Thomine ha! you are right. Many thanks.